# Cabal not finding sources

Tags: haskell, cabal

While playing with [semver](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semver) and [semver-range](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semver-range) I was stuck because of conflicting modules name.

As a temporary fix, I forked the semver-range repo to rename modules (the first attempt is available [here](https://github.com/ThomasCrvsr/semver-range/tree/weird-cabal-stuff)). I renamed each modules `Data.SemVer*` by `Data.SemVer.Range*`.

I didn't change the folder structure, just the cabal file :

```
Exposed-modules:     Data.SemVer.Range
other-modules:       Data.SemVer.Range.Parser
                   , Data.SemVer.Range.Types
```

Trying to build the project I have the following error message :

```
Building semver-range-0.2.0...
Preprocessing library semver-range-0.2.0...
cabal: can't find source for Data/SemVer/Range in src, dist/build/autogen
```

I made a second attempt (available [here](https://github.com/ThomasCrvsr/semver-range/tree/master)). I renamed every module `Data.SemVer*` with `Data.SemVerRange*`

I also changed the cabal file and renamed `src/Data/SemVer.hs` to `src/Data/SemVerRange.hs`.

This second attempt worked fine but I'm curious what did I do wrong in the first try.

Did I miss something obvious ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little bit confused about the precise sequence of renames you've done, but anyway... Looking at your first attempt, I see a file that says

```
module Data.SemVer.Range.Types where
```

However, the filename is is `src/Data/SemVer/Types.hs`, which doesn't match. And that would be why it doesn't work; file path doesn't match module path.

If you had created a folder named `Range` and moved the files in there, that should work.